# Oracle Forms Developer 6i: EXECUTE_QUERY do not working after ENTER_QUERY Mode

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have 2 data block 'Employee' as master and 'Employee_Details' as details and 1 control block for navigation. I have used my menu and usually the default developer toolbar was not appeared. So I place a Enter-Query button to serve the purpose. I used when-button-pressed trigger.

```
GO_BLOCK('EMPLOYEE');
IF :System.Mode = 'NORMAL' THEN 
    Enter_Query;
ELSE
    EXECUTE_QUERY;
END IF;
```

In first trigger the Form goes to Enter-Query Mode. But when I pressed for Execute_Query it does not work. Rather it shows in status bar to press F8 to do query and Ctrl+q for cancel. I tried it to place the code in different button but not working. I do not want to press F8 for execute query. Why my button code not working for Executing Query? Have you any solution?

Comment: Please clarify: have you deliberately suppressed the default toolbar?  If not, shouldn't you be trying to solve that problem instead?

Comment: Yes I suppressed the default toolbar. @APC

Comment: In fact I got an answer from another forum. This method will work only with default where clause. The built-in enter_query and execute_query system only available in default toolbar.

Comment: Please write that up as an answer, and accept it (when SO allows you to).

Comment: I'm sure that you are able to use built-ins Enter_Query and Ececute_Query even if you don't use the default toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem probably is that there are a few options with your trigger.
One of them is if it will fire when in enter query mode.
Because you are in enter-query mode right now this switch should be true.
Then it will work.

The default for the switch is false, so no trigger will fire in enter-query mode.

Comment: What kind of option you are talking? In when-button-press trigger I just wrote those codes. there are no other codes.

Comment: Firstly thanks to Nightfox79 for drawing the attention to this issue.. In fact I changed the strategy of my works but I checked the code again in another test form and it works. Although I don't know what was the problem in trigger property that time...!